# Can I use silicone "window & door" caulk between a kitchen counter and backsplash?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, backsplash, caulk

I need to caulk my granite counter-top and ceramic tile back-splash. The big box store only has "kitchen" caulk in white, clear and almond. These colors are not going to work for me, I really want to use gray but the store only has gray silicone caulk that is labeled for "windows, doors, and basements" ([GE Silicone II Caulk](http://www.caulkyourhome.com/ge-silicone-II-window-and-door.php)).

Can I use this in my kitchen?

It does not look that different from the same "GE Silicone II" caulk meant for kitchens and bath.  Should I look for a gray caulk that is labeled for use in the kitchen?

Comment: I think the key is to confuse your caulk.  Maybe start off on a door, put a rag over it, and then just appear in the kitchen.  Maybe your caulk isn't bright so just tell him he is in a basement.  Worst case scenario the caulk quits and leaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm tempted to say the difference is just marketing hype, you can use either one, there is a very slight difference in formulation. The window and door stuff has slightly less petroleum distillates in the formula, according to MSDS information at nih.gov. Petroleum distillates will evaporate during curing, so I'm unsure why there's a difference. The difference is so small however, I'm confident you can use one or the other with no noticeable difference in the final installation.

Answer (score 1):

An exterior rated product will be good in the kitchen.

The version you linked is a "3 hr rain ready" version, so you want to do any tooling ASAP.  I like to put 2 tape lines of (blue or other painters edging tape) above and below the joint. Gun the entire line and then "thumb squeegee" the joint.

Pull the tape off and immediately touch up with a rag dampened with mineral spirits, if necessary.